# animateWithKeyFrameAnimation producing different results in different parts of my class

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to animate a view based on a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. In the beginning, the view should move with the user's finger on the x-axis and rotate. After the view has moved the set amount, it should simply slide off the screen. Imagine a card being slid off a deck.

For the final sliding, I am using `animateWithKeyFrameAnimation`. While I was testing it I simply put it in a function and hooked it up to a `UIButton`. So the view would move with my finger and then simply stop once I hit the maximum moved limit. I would then tap the button mentioned above and the view would seamlessly slide off of the screen.

Then I added that "sliding off the screen" animation code inside my gesture handler function. And now the view flashes off the screen, quickly slides back to where it was, and then animates off. I even tried just calling the function from inside the gesture handler and I got the same result.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here? I don't understand why calling the code in one place would produce such vastly different results. Also, how do I fix it?

**Code**

I am moving the `anchorPoint` without moving the view for rotation point purposes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        movingView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        movingView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: movingView.frame.size)
    }
```

This is the function that the `gestureRecognizer` is hooked to.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let screenWidth = screenBounds.width
    let percentMovedBeforeRemoving = CGFloat(0.8)
    let totalMovedBeforeRemoving = (screenWidth / 2) * percentMovedBeforeRemoving

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(view)

    if  abs(totalMoved) >= totalMovedBeforeRemoving {
        finishAnimatingOffScreen(nil)
        //I also tried putting the code in here with the same strange results

    } else {
        // This is what moves the view with the finger in the first place
        let percentToRotate = translation.x / (screenBounds.width / 2)

        totalRotated += CGFloat(percentToRotate * totalRotation)
        totalMoved += translation.x

        movingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(totalRotated)
        movingView.center = CGPoint(x: (movingView.center.x + translation.x), y: movingView.center.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
}
```

And this is the function that animates the view the rest of the way off of the screen.

```
@IBAction func finishAnimatingOffScreen(sender: UIButton?) {
        print(movingView.frame)
        let totalRotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI / 12))
        let finalViewFrame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.movingView.frame, totalRotationTransform)
        let xToMove: CGFloat = -(finalViewFrame.width / 2 + self.movingView.center.x)

        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.CalculationModeCubic], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0.01, animations: {
                self.movingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.totalRotated)
                self.movingView.center = CGPoint(x: (self.movingView.center.x), y: self.movingView.center.y)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.01, relativeDuration: 4.99, animations :{
                let moveOffScreenTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xToMove, 0)
                let rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI / 12))
                self.movingView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moveOffScreenTransform, rotateTransform)
            })
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using auto layout. After you move the view, you are calling `finishAnimatingOffScreen` but before that happens the auto layout engine is doing a pass and returning your view to it's original constraints then proceeding with the animation. You should update constraints rather setting frames or centers for the views you want to animate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read what you're saying about auto-layout. But then why does the code work when I just press the button? (Wouldn't it go through the same layout steps there?)

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the view while it's being animated and that is messing up the animation.

You should disable the panGesture while it's animating. For example:

```
if  abs(totalMoved) >= totalMovedBeforeRemoving {
        recognizer.enabled = false
        finishAnimatingOffScreen(nil)
    }
```

then at the end of `finishAnimatingOffScreen` say:

```
UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.01, relativeDuration: 4.99, animations :{
                let moveOffScreenTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xToMove, 0)
                let rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI / 12))
                self.movingView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moveOffScreenTransform, rotateTransform)
            })


              }, completion:{ _ in
                   self.panGesture.enabled = true
          })
```

I would say it is a good rule of thump to update constraints rather than frames when using auto layout though.